# streamR character problem when analysing tweet

Tags: r, twitter, stream

```
file = "tweets.json"
track = "kikik,kükükü,üğüğü"
lang = "tr"
minutes = 0.5
time = 60*minutes
filterStream(file.name = file, 
             track = track,
             language = lang,
             timeout = time, 
             oauth = my_oauth)
```

When I use this code and start capturing  tweet from my account does not find that tweet. This error only happens when I use the İ,Ö,Ü,Ğ characters. ı changed encode setting but not working. what can ı do?